# make sans serif font light in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

I want to make sans serif font light in LaTeX. I use `\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{ul}\selectfont}` command but it doesn't change anything. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you considered to add an MWE showing what you have tried so far? Please see question https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: cmss has no ul series.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. What series does it have then?